# How do I build custom options for sections?

Tags: 8, layout-builder

I manage to build/define some custom blocks with my own parameters/form elements when placing them, so I'm looking to do the same with sections. I've seen that the core code does that, but ideally I would like to add more form elements to that interface and allow the editors to customise a bit more the abilities of each section. I found the core file that contains the functions but doesn't feel right to me to just copy the whole file and modify it for my purpose.

I also found [this module](https://www.drupal.org/project/layout_section_classes) that seems that does what I'm after but has some issues I think.

I made a layout module in order to define some basic layouts (4 of them) and now I'm trying to do the above. The code is as follow:

#### hs_layout.module file

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function hs_layout_form_layout_builder_add_block_alter(array &$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['settings']['admin_label'] = [];
  $form['settings']['label'] = [];
  $form['settings']['label_display'] = [];
}

/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function hs_layout_form_layout_builder_update_block_alter(array &$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['settings']['admin_label'] = [];
  $form['settings']['label'] = [];
  $form['settings']['label_display'] = [];
}
```

#### HsOneColumnLayout.php file

```php
namespace Drupal\hs_layout\Plugin;

use Drupal\Core\Layout\LayoutDefault;
use Drupal\Core\Plugin\PluginFormInterface;

/**
 * Class HsOneColumnLayout.
 *
 * @package Drupal\hs_layout\Plugin
 */
class HsOneColumnLayout extends LayoutDefault implements PluginFormInterface {
}
```

Comment: This question doesn't really fit DA's  narrow question & answer format. Please take a look at the [docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/layout-api/how-to-register-layouts) first and create a new, more specific question if any problems arise.

Comment: It is specific, because I need a way to add options to my custom layout sections. How much more specific than that?

Comment: So can you show us your code, what have you tried and which problem couldn't be solved? Asking for **any documentation** and **a methodology** is not specific at all.

Comment: I edited the question with some of the code I use to define the layouts.